# One-liner to remove all files except those matching a few patterns from a directory with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I can remove all files except those matching a pattern `string` in a `directory` using `find directory/ -type f ! -name 'string' -delete` . However, I am running into trouble saving more than one pattern. E.g., consider `directory` with contents:

```
string1_1
string2_1
string3_1
string4_1
sdfsdv2_1
```

I'd like to delete everything except string1_1, string2_1,and string3_1. I tried several things, but the closest I got was `find directory/ -type f ! -name 'string1_'||'string2_'||'string3_' -delete`. This performs the find properly but prints the file names rather than deleting them. That is, it prints:

```
string4_1
sdfsdv2_1
```

What modification can I do to do this in one line? Obvious multi-line workarounds exist, like storing the `find` output in a text file and `rm`-ing based on that, but I'd like to do this in one line.

There's a couple answers on here that use scripts, but this seems like it's scratching the surface of a good one-line answer. If this question's been answered before verbatim, I've missed it, so please link.

Comment: `find directory/ -type f ! \( -name 'string1_*' -o -name 'string2_*' -o -name 'string3_*' \) -delete`?

Comment: That gives the error `find: invalid expression; I was expecting to find a ')' somewhere but did not see one.` 

Same command without the space between ( and -name gives the error `find: paths must precede expression: (-name`

Comment: Did you include all whitespace and quotes? That error sounds like you might have inputted `'string3_*'\)`

Comment: Nice! That did work. Thanks a ton. Could you make yours an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I added it to my existing answer with some context on why `||` failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `find directory/ -type f ! -name 'string1_'||'string2_'||'string3_' -delete`

This says "find files not named string1_, and **execute a command named string2_** if find exits non-zero" `||` is not find syntax as far as I can tell, it's bash syntax.

The (GNU) find syntax for chaining tests is to concatenate them with `-o`. To test if a file matches pattern A or B, you use `-name A -o -name B`. To test the inverse you can wrap the whole expression in parentheses and negate it: `! \( -name A -o -name B \)`.

In your specific case you can use: `find directory/ -type f ! \( -name 'string1_*' -o -name 'string2_*' -o -name 'string3_*' \) -delete`

Answer (score 1):

With bash's [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```bash
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' !(string[123]_1)
```

change `printf '%s\n'`  to `rm` if the output looks like the list of files you want to delete.

This does not descend into subdirectories like `find` does.